# Aliasing a service lazy loaded from a module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-services, angular-module

If I define a Route in my AppModule to alias a provider that is included in the module, like so:

```
{
  path: "my-path",
  loadComponent: () => import('./my-component'),
  providers: [
    {
      provide: IBaseService,
      useClass: AliasService
    }
  ]
}
```

It gives the AliasService to the component, as expected.

On the other hand, if I need to import the service from a lazy loaded module, the base way is to use loadChildren:

```
{
  path: "my-path",
  loadComponent: () => import('./my-component'),
  loadChildren: () => import('./my-module')
}
```

Assuming my module has `IBaseService` included in its providers list, this give IBaseService to the component.

The trouble arises when I need to import an alias service from a lazy loaded module. The providers list doesn't appear to have any members that support lazy loading (useFactory, for what it's worth, doesn't allow Observables to be returned), and loadComponent doesn't support aliases.

I tried defining an alias in the lazy loaded module, but for some reason it doesn't seem be finding that. Either I decorate the base service and it returns that instead of the alias service, or it complains that it can't find the base service despite having the alias provider declared.

I suspect that this last has something to do with the alias service being in module scope instead of app scope, but then I would think it wouldn't provide the IBaseService when it's configured that way.

Anyway, whether something needs to be done on the module side or the appmodule side, what can I do to get the correct alias to my component?